# Alternative to getDeclaredField("mBase") on Android 5

Tags: android, android-context, android-dialog

On Android 4.4 and below I am using the following code to *setAccessible(true)* and get the context for a dialog:

```
    private Context getOriginalContextForDialog(Dialog dialog) {
    try {
        if (dialog == null || (dialog != null && dialog.getContext() == null)){
            return null;
        }

        Field field = dialog.getContext().getClass().getDeclaredField("mBase");

        field.setAccessible(true);
        Context value = (Context) field.get(dialog.getContext());
        return value;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logProc.errSys(LogSubcategory.USER_NOTICE, "Error getting dialog context on UIProcImpl.dismissProgressDialog.", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This returns an exception in Android 5 because "mBase" is not found. I cannot find out what the equivalent is on Android 5.  I added "getDeclaredFields" to see what values were returned. Attached are screenshots of some of the data in the array returned from "getDeclaredFields". I have highlighted with red in the screenshot from Android 4.4 which shows "mBase". The other screenshot is from Android 5 and it does not include "mBase".

What would be the equivalent for "mBase" in Android 5? Or how should I better code this to support both 4.4 and 5?

**Android 4.4**
[image: Android 4.4]

**Android 5**
[image: Android 5]

Comment: Are meaning about ContextWrapper.getBaseContext() ?

Comment: `dialog.getContext()` returns context why do you doing this?

Comment: So I can use "setAccessible(true).

Comment: See my answer. I don't know why do you using reflections. You don't need this.

Comment: getBaseContext is public api. You can use it. Activity is instance of ContextWrapper so you can cast this to ContextWrapper but the better way is to test it as in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get the base context from dialog:

```
Dialog dialog; // your dialog
Context context = dialog.getContext();
if(context instanceof ContextWrapper)
{
     context = ((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();
}

return context;
```

Edit:

`instanceof` operator is used to check if object is instance of class.

Example:

```
Context context = dialog.getContext();
if(context instanceof ArrayList){ // false because context is not instance of ArrayList
}

Object object = context;
if(object instanceof Context){ // true 

}
```

Comment: I inherited this code so I am still learning what was done and why.  Don't I need "field.setAccessible(true)".

Comment: Not a beginner in software engineering but at Android development.

Comment: @Mark See my edited answer. I hope it helped you why I am used this code. Link to documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext()

Comment: @Mark You can see this too - this is source of ContextWrapper. This method returns mBase and you don't need to use reflections. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.getBaseContext%28%29

Comment: Thank you. You have given me some information to work with. I am going to change the code and run some tests. I will come back and accept the answer.

Comment: My concern was the "field.setAccessible(true)" was removed. I will take your information and run some tests.

Comment: @Mark I was forgotten. Dialog.getContext() returns context passed in constructor. If you want to use this context to create views you don't need to get the base context.